# Robocopy - ERROR 87 (0x00000057) Accessing Destination Directory

Tags: robocopy

I'm currently using a robocopy in a loop performing the following command over a number of different directories:

```
robocopy $sourceFolder $purgeFolder /MOV /LEV:0 /MINAGE:$OlderThan
```

All source folder paths are at the same level in our directory structure and have exactly the same permissions however when the loop reaches certain directories robocopy just continually reports `ERROR 87 (0x00000057) Accessing Destination Directory`. The script is being run with a service account with full control over the directories and files, and when I run the script myself I don't encounter the same issues. Robocopy itself creates the `$purgeFolder` successfully however then reports it can't access it.

Comment: Might be worth running Process Monitor to see what exactly is happening from the file system's point of view when robocopy fails.

Comment: After reading [https://serverfault.com/questions/892031/robocopy-error-50-accessing-destination-directory-request-is-not-supported?answertab=active#tab-top](https://serverfault.com/questions/892031/robocopy-error-50-accessing-destination-directory-request-is-not-supported?answertab=active#tab-top)
Adding /COPY:DT /DCOPY:T fixed the issue.